# How to move an object with sound?

Tags: animation, workflow, audio

I'm making an intro with music, and I have objects that need to move with the music. It's not on the beat, slightly random, so I can't use regular intervals.
Is there a way to do this? I'm not sure if you can use a similar method to lip syncing. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com) audio workflow we usually parent a speaker to an object and then animate that object.![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KqijK.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bake sounds to fcurves:

1. Insert a keyframe (<kbd>`I`</kbd>) on the transform channel you want to be controlled by the sound (e.g. Z scale).
2. In the *Graph editor*, press *Key > Bake sound to fcurves* and navigate to a sound file. Optionally change the import settings at the bottom of the tool shelf in the file manager:

   [image]
3. Press enter.

Now that channel will change according to the baked fcurve.

[image]

Comment: On Blender version 3.6.5 this option can be found in the "Channel" menu next to the "Key" menu